# Posit Cloud Crashing using RMarkdown

Tags: crash

I am receiving this error on Posit Cloud:  "There was a problem with the task, please try again. (Task 7e39cfd1-99ff-4087-8d57-49feadc97731)"

in the middle of running code, added new code using table1 package in RMarkdown. The program hung and now I can't open any files on Posit Cloud.  I rebooted and cleared cache.  I have reached out to tech support.